# Testing ionic2 in a real android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I've built an app using ionic2 + cordova, now I am trying to run this in a real device. I have already set up all the things I had to, such as: %JAVA_HOME%, %ANDROID_HOME%, %ANT_HOME% and all the paths as well. However, as I try to run the command: ionic cordova run android, I recevive this error: "CORDOVA IS NOT A VALID TASK".

When I run: "ionic run android" I get this another error: "No emulator images (avds) found, if you would like to create an
 avd follow the instructions provided here:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html
 Or run 'android create avd --name  --target '
 in on the command line."

Please, I am new in the mobile world, so I thought about starting a small POC, but I am not even being able to run this in my cellphone. Could someone help me out in this issue? I would appreciate it

Comment: Make sure you have a real device connected to your computer and then run `adb devices` to check if adb is recognizing it.

Comment: @akz92, thanks for replying me, I did I want you advised me, I ran the following command: adb devices and it responded with: "List of devices attached ". Curiously, the list shows nothing, which means my laptop isnt recognizing any device, I have two connected (Iphone, Samsung Galaxy) though... any guess?

Comment: ADB only recognizes Android devices, and in order for it to recognize your device you need to enable Debugging Mode on the Developer Settings of the device. Check out this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

Comment: @akz92 Thank you very much, thanks to you I made it, now the app is running in my prsonal phone! Do you know how I can mark this topic as solved?

Comment: I'll move my comments to an answer so you can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADB only recognizes Android devices, and in order for it to recognize your device you need to enable Debugging Mode on the Developer Settings of the device. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/).

Comment: Thanks once more for your help